# How do I determine this probability?

Tags: probability

If there is an color event which occurs once every 28 minutes. When this event occurs there are two colors produced. There is a 50% chance that the color will be red or black. Only when the color is red will there be a second 5% chance that a second color of red produced. There can only be at most one black OR two reds.

All colors are cleared after each event and do not carry over to the next event.

How can I determine the probability over time of two red colors occurring?

It would also be nice to see this graphed if possible.

---

Let me clarify. The probability I'm looking for is specifically for obtaining to reds when graphed over time. For example, when graphed the probability would go UP over time as it becomes more probably as the sample size increases.

Comment: Is not it $50\%\times 5\%$?

Comment: Is it possible to understand a query so that the probability distribution of time between events is exponential with a mean value of 28 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

There are in total three possibilities:

a) Both Red = $50\%\cdot5\%$

b) 1st Red and 2nd Black = $50\%\cdot95\%$

c) 1st Black and 2nd Red =$50\%$

After 2 events the probability of a) would be $(50\%\cdot5\%)\cdot(50\%\cdot5\%)=(50\%\cdot5\%)^{2}$

So after $n$ events probability that every event was a) would be **$(50\%\cdot5\%)^{n}$** **or** $(\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{20})^{n}$

Graph would be something like this

[image]

Comment: I've clarified the question.

Comment: "How can I determine the probability over time of two red colours occurring?" Does this means that you are talking about even a)? Or you want at least two red colours over time? BTW the graph is probability vs time. the x-axis denotes time with each value of x is 28 minutes.